# Unwind nested JSON object with possible null values using jq?

Tags: json, jq

I have a json response with 3 items that looks like this:

```
{
    "id": 44,
    "extra": [{
        "domain": {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "person"
        },
        "entity": {
            "label": "Noon",
            "serial": 8938493
        }
    },
    {
        "domain": {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "place"
        },
        "entity": {
            "label": "Rad",
            "serial": 8932321
        }
    }]
}
{
    "id": 45,
    "extra": null
    
}
{
    "id": 46,
    "extra": [{
        "domain": {
            "id": 90,
            "name": "animal"
        },
        "entity": {
            "label": "Foo",
            "serial": 892121
        }
    },
    {
        "domain": {
            "id": 91
        },
        "entity": {
            "label": "Ear",
            "serial": 823414
        }
    },
    {
        "domain": {
            "id": 92
        },
        "entity": {
            "label": "Owl",
            "serial": 889232
        }
    }]
}
```

My goal is to get this response into:

```
{
    "id": 44,
    "extra_domain_id": 3,
    "extra_domain_name": "person",
    "extra_entity_label": "Noon",
    "extra_entity_serial": 8938493
},
{
    "id": 44,
    "extra_domain_id": 4,
    "extra_domain_name": "place",
    "extra_entity_label": "Rad",
    "extra_entity_serial": 8932321
},
{
    "id": 45,
    "extra_domain_id": null,
    "extra_domain_name": null,
    "extra_entity_label": null,
    "extra_entity_serial": null
},
{
    "id": 46,
    "extra_domain_id": 90,
    "extra_domain_name": "animal",
    "extra_entity_label": "Foo",
    "extra_entity_serial": 892121
},
{
    "id": 46,
    "extra_domain_id": 91,
    "extra_domain_name": null,
    "extra_entity_label": "Ear",
    "extra_entity_serial": 823414
},
{
    "id": 46,
    "extra_domain_id": 92,
    "extra_domain_name": null,
    "extra_entity_label": "Owl",
    "extra_entity_serial": 889232
}
```

Notice how in the third item with `id` 46, `domain.name` is missing in the last two entries, 91 and 92 of the `extra` array, so they're replaced with null. 
This is what I tried

```
{"id": .id, "extra_domain_id": .extra[].domain.id, "extra_domain_name": .extra[].domain.name, "extra_entity_label": .extra[].entity.label, "extra_entity_serial": .extra[].entity.serial}
```

but it doesn't give me the desired output, it returns a cartesian product of all possible combinations in each item in the response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring for the moment that the expected output as shown is not strictly speaking valid JSON, one possible solution would be to use an invocation such as:

```
jq -nf program.jq input.json
```

where program.jq contains:

```
[inputs
 | {id} +
   ((.extra[]? // {})
    | {"extra_domain_id": .domain.id,
       "extra_domain_name": .domain.name,
       "extra_entity_label": .entity.label,
       "extra_entity_serial": .entity.serial} ) ]
```

This produces an array with the desired objects.  If you wish to produce the invalid JSON as shown in the Q, feel free to employ whatever devious device that occurs to you, e.g. stripping away the leading and trailing square brackets.

### Notes

1. `{"id": .id}` can be abbreviated as shown.
2. Notice how the combinatorial explosion is avoided by specifying the itemization just once.
3. The postfix "?" in an expression `E?` has the effect of `try E catch empty`
4. To handle the `empty` case, `//` has been used.
5. If you wanted a stream of valid JSON objects as the output, you could simplify things a bit by dropping the `-n` option and the use of `inputs` to wrap everything into an array.

Comment: so is this not a proper json because it's missing the outermost curly braces?

Comment: The outermost square brackets are missing.